# MongoDB merge two collections with unmatched documents

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to compare and find different documents from two collections
below are the samples, **Mongodb version:4.0**, **ORM:mongoose**

```
**col1: Has one new document**

    { "id" : 200001, "mobileNo" : #######001 }
    { "id" : 200002, "mobileNo" : #######002 } //mobileNo may not be unique.
    { "id" : 200003, "mobileNo" : #######002 }
    { "id" : 200004, "mobileNo" : #######004 }

**col2:**

    { "id" : 200001, "mobileNo" : #######001 }
    { "id" : 200002, "mobileNo" : #######002 }
    { "id" : 200003, "mobileNo" : #######003 }
```

Now I want to insert the document `{ "id" : 200004, "mobileNo" : #######004 }` from `col1` to `col2`
i.e; the documents which doesn't match.

This is what I've tried so far :

```
const col1= await Col1.find({}, { mobileNo: 1,id: 1, _id: 0 })
 col1.forEach(async function (col1docs) {
    let col2doc = await Col2.find({ mobileNo: { $ne: col1docs.mobileNo}, 
    id:{$ne:col1docs.id} }, { mobileNo: 1, _id: 0, id: 1 })
     if (!(col2doc)) {
            Col2.insertMany(col1docs);

            }
        });
```

I have also tried with $eq instead of $ne but neither i am getting the unmatched documents nor they are getting inserted. Any suggestions??? **Combination of id+phoneNo is unique**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say instead of doing two `.find()` calls plus iteration & then third call to write data, try this query :

```
db.col1.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "col2",
        let: { id: "$id", mobileNo: "$mobileNo" },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: { $expr: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$id", "$$id" ] }, { $gte: [ "$mobileNo", "$$mobileNo" ] } ] } }
          },
          { $project: { _id: 1 } } // limiting to `_id` as we don't need entire doc of `col2` - just need to see whether a ref exists or not
        ],
        as: "data"
      }
    },
    { $match: { data: [] } // Filtering leaves docs in `col1` which has no match in `col2`
    },
    { $project: { data: 0, _id: 0 } }
 ])
```

**Test :** [mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xVdUKAq9iVc)

**Details :** From the above query you're taking advantage of specifying conditions in  [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#specify-multiple-join-conditions-with-lookup) to get docs from `col1` which have reference in `col2`. Let's say `$lookup` will run on each document of `col1` - So with the unique combination of `id & mobileNo` from current document in `col1` has a matching in `col2` then `col2` doc's `_id` will be pushed in `data` array, at the end what we get out of `col1` is `data: []` to say no matching docs were found for these `col1` doc's. Now you can just write all the returned docs to `col2` using `.insertMany()`. Actually you can do this entire thing using [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html) on MongoDB version > `4.2` without any need of 2nd write call(`.insertMany()`).

For your scenario on MongoDB version > `4.2` something like this will merge docs to second collection :

```
{ $merge: 'col2' } // Has to be final stage in aggregation
```

**Note :** If this has to be done periodically - no matter how you do this, try to minimize data that you're operating on, maybe maintain a time field & you can use that field to filter docs first & do this job, or you can also take advantage of `_id` to say we've done for all these docs in last run & we need to start from this docs - which helps you a lot to reduce data to be worked on. Additionally don't forget to maintain indexes.

Comment: Thanks @whoami i tried your logic but it didn't work it does not fetch any documents when i try to filter `{ $match: { data: [] }` else it returns all the matching documents when i dont filter it out

Comment: @sachin.pandey : Did you test it in playground, It should be working. Do you think you've all docs in `Coll1` has matching docs in `Coll2` only then all docs will have something in `data` array field..

Comment: lets chat i would be able to share actual data

Comment: Thanks very much @whoami figured out where i was wrong.. its working :-))